# Sieve of Eratosthenes - Standard and Optimized implementation

Tags: python, primes, numpy, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am a Java developer who is taking Python for the first time.

I'm sure this is not at all elegant since I am thinking more in C syntax.

```
"""
This module contains two implementations of the algorithm Sieve of
Eratosthenes. 
"""

# import ############################################################### import #
import math
import numpy
#
 # fun1 ################################################################# fun1 #
def SieveBasic(n):
 """
 This function runs the basic sieve of eratosthenis algorithm (non-optimized)
 and returns a list of prime numbers. The algorithm is implemented as described @:
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Example

 """

 l = list(range(2, n+1))
 isPrime = [True] * (n-1)

 for m,n in enumerate(l):
     currentCheck = n
     for i,x in enumerate(l[m+1:]): #take each number and compare with later numbers
       if x % currentCheck == 0:
            isPrime[i+m+1] = False

 primes = [0,1]
 for i,x in enumerate(isPrime):
     if x==True:
         primes.append(2+i)

 return primes  


 """
 This function generates a list of Js required for optimized sieve of eratosthenis algorithm.

 """
def generateJs(i,n):
    j=i**2  
    if j<n:    
        yield j    

    while j+i<=n:
        j+=i
        yield j


def SieveOptimized(n):
 """
 This function runs the optimized sieve of eratosthenis algorithm 
 and returns a list of prime numbers. The algorithm is implemented as described @:
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Implementation

 """
 l = list(range(2, n+1))
 isPrime = [True] * (n+1)
 maxChk = math.sqrt(n) 

 for q,r in enumerate(l):
    if r>maxChk:
        break

    for z in generateJs(r,n): 
       isPrime[z] = False    

 return numpy.where(isPrime)[0] # how cool is this
```

Comment: SieveBasic is not a true Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm, as the true Sieve algorithm has no division nor modulus operations, only additions.  This looks more like the notorious Trial Division algorithm.

Comment: The actual basic algorithm is correctly described at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_description

Comment: I must protest :) your characterization of `BasicSieve` as implementation of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Example. It is nothing of the sorts; that page specifically speaks of counting up in increments of `p` to find all multiples of `p`, and doing so only for the yet-not-marked entries in the array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Style**

You code does not follow [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the usual Python coding convention. You'll find tools such as `pep8` (or its [online version](http://pep8online.com/)), `pylint`, `pyflakes` or `pychecker` to check for this and other points that might make your code cleaner, more idiomatic or more correct.

I can't be bothered to break the too long lines nor to fix typos in the comments but I did perform the other changes so make `pep8` happy.

The result is :

```
"""
This module contains two implementations of the algorithm Sieve of
Eratosthenes.
"""

import math
import numpy


def SieveBasic(n):
    """
    This function runs the basic sieve of eratosthenis algorithm (non-optimized)
    and returns a list of prime numbers. The algorithm is implemented as described @:
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Example
    """
    l = list(range(2, n+1))
    isPrime = [True] * (n-1)

    for m, n in enumerate(l):
        currentCheck = n
        # take each number and compare with later numbers
        for i, x in enumerate(l[m+1:]):
            if x % currentCheck == 0:
                isPrime[i+m+1] = False

    primes = [0, 1]
    for i, prime in enumerate(isPrime):
        if prime:
            primes.append(2+i)

    return primes


def generateJs(i, n):
    """
    This function generates a list of Js required for optimized sieve of eratosthenis algorithm.
    """
    j = i**2
    if j < n:
        yield j

    while j+i <= n:
        j += i
        yield j


def SieveOptimized(n):
    """
        This function runs the optimized sieve of eratosthenis algorithm
        and returns a list of prime numbers. The algorithm is implemented as described @:
        http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Implementation

    """
    l = list(range(2, n+1))
    isPrime = [True] * (n+1)
    maxChk = math.sqrt(n)

    for q, r in enumerate(l):
        if r > maxChk:
            break

        for z in generateJs(r, n):
            isPrime[z] = False

    return numpy.where(isPrime)[0]


def main():
    """Main function"""
    for n in range(1, 200):
        s1 = SieveBasic(n)
        s2 = SieveOptimized(n).tolist()
        if s1 != s2:
            print n, s1, s2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also, the name of `generateJs` is not so great as it doesn't tell us much.

**Correctness**

When you write two functions to perform the same thing, it can be a good idea to check that you get the same result on a big set of inputs. Here's what I wrote :

```
def main():
    """Main function"""
    for n in range(1, 200):
        s1 = SieveBasic(n)
        s2 = SieveOptimized(n).tolist()
        if s1 != s2:
            print n, s1, s2
```

This shows that the result is different when n is 4, 9, 25, 49, 121, 169. The optimised algorithm consider these values as prime even though they shouldn't (as they are perfect squares - of prime numbers which might have its importance when looking for the fix). Once this is fixed, you can use `assert` to ensure the results of the two functions are the same.

In your case, the fix is simple : changing `if j < n` for `if j <= n` in `generateJs` :

```
def generateJs(i, n):
    """
    This function generates a list of Js required for optimized sieve of eratosthenis algorithm.
    """
    j = i**2
    if j <= n:
        yield j

    while j+i <= n:
        j += i
        yield
```

`0` and `1` shouldn't be considered as primes. Again, fixing this is simple : initialising `primes` as being `primes = []` in the basic function and setting `isPrime[0] = isPrime[1] = False` in the optimised function.

**Improving the code for the optimised version**

In `generateJs`, you can factorise code by writing :

```
def generateJs(i, n):
    """
    This function generates a list of Js required for optimized sieve of eratosthenis algorithm.
    """
    j = i**2
    while j <= n:
        yield j
        j += i
```

Interestingly, this now looks a lot like `range` (or `xrange` depending on the version of Python you are using). We can get rid of it and write :

Also, you don't need to use `enumerate`:

```
def SieveOptimized(n):
    """
        This function runs the optimized sieve of eratosthenis algorithm
        and returns a list of prime numbers. The algorithm is implemented as described @:
        http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Implementation

    """
    l = list(range(2, n+1))
    isPrime = [True] * (n+1)
    isPrime[0] = isPrime[1] = False
    maxChk = math.sqrt(n)

    for r in l:
        if r > maxChk:
            break

        for z in xrange(r*r, n+1, r):
            isPrime[z] = False

    return numpy.where(isPrime)[0]
```

Now, if you think about it, the list `l` is not that useful. The point is just to perform a re-indexing : what we are really doing is that we loop starting as `2` and we stop at `n` (included). We can write this directly : `for r in xrange(2, n+1):`. The same kind of comment also applies to the "basic" version of the code.

```
def SieveOptimized(n):
    """
        This function runs the optimized sieve of eratosthenis algorithm
        and returns a list of prime numbers. The algorithm is implemented as described @:
        http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Implementation

    """
    isPrime = [True] * (n+1)
    isPrime[0] = isPrime[1] = False
    maxChk = math.sqrt(n)

    for r in xrange(2, n+1):
        if r > maxChk:
            break

        for z in xrange(r*r, n+1, r):
            isPrime[z] = False

    return numpy.where(isPrime)[0]
```

Because `sqrt(n) + 1 <= n + 1` for any `n >= 1`, we can use `maxChk` in the call to range :

```
def SieveOptimized(n):
    """
        This function runs the optimized sieve of eratosthenis algorithm
        and returns a list of prime numbers. The algorithm is implemented as described @:
        http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Implementation

    """
    isPrime = [True] * (n+1)
    isPrime[0] = isPrime[1] = False

    for r in xrange(2, int(math.sqrt(n))+1):
        for z in xrange(r*r, n+1, r):
            isPrime[z] = False

    return numpy.where(isPrime)[0]
```

**Improving the code for the basic version**

Here again, the list `l` is not that useful. The point is just to perform a re-indexing : what we are really doing is that we loop starting as `2` and we stop at `n` (included).

You can put a few `assert`s in your code to double check that we don't really need the values from `l` as we can compute them.

```
for m, n in enumerate(l):
    assert m == n-2
    assert n == m+2
    currentCheck = m+2
    # take each number and compare with later numbers
    for i, x in enumerate(l[m+1:]):
        assert x - m - i == 3
        assert x == 3 + m + i
        if x % currentCheck == 0:
            isPrime[i+m+1] = False
```

Messing a bit with indices, you get :

```
def SieveBasic(n):
    """
    This function runs the basic sieve of eratosthenis algorithm (non-optimized)
    and returns a list of prime numbers. The algorithm is implemented as described @:
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Example
    """
    isPrime = [True] * (n-1)

    for x in range(2, n+1):
        # take each number and compare with later numbers
        for j in range(x+1, n+1):
            if j % x == 0:
                isPrime[j - 2] = False

    primes = []
    for i, prime in enumerate(isPrime):
        if prime:
            primes.append(2+i)

    return primes
```

And the end of the function can be re-written with a list comprehension :

```
return [2+i for i, prime in enumerate(isPrime) if prime]
```

This code is still not optimal but because it corresponds to the "basic" version, I guess there is no need to try to make it too much better.

**Additional note**

In my code, I've been using `range` and `xrange` as I am used to switch between Python 2 and Python 3. Depending on the version you are using, I suggest you have a look online to see more details about this. Just keep in mind that you should try to avoid creating a list when an iterator is enough for you.